# Does PDO::beginTransaction() cause table or row locking until PDO::commit()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP script that does around 1,000 inserts and 1,000 updates each loop using prepared statements. It loops as long as work needs to be done, sometimes for hours, and is causing performance problems (including deadlock exceptions).

I am trying to improve performance and am looking into bulk inserts and updates (although I'm still trying to figure out how to even do bulk updates).

When `PDO::beginTransaction()` is called, does it simply tell the PDO class not to send queries excecuted with `PDO::execute()` to the database, or does it send the query and then lock the tables/rows used until `PDO::commit()` is called?

The reason I ask is that the PHP script takes up to 50 seconds each loop and it makes the insert and update queries over that time span, so I'm trying to figure out if I can simply add `PDO::beginTransaction()` at the beginning of the script and `PDO::commit()` at the end.

Comment: Batching 100 or 1000 rows in a single INSERT statement will run 10 times as fast as individual-row INSERTs.  What do your UPDATEs look like?  Can they be combined by using a suitable WHERE clause?

Comment: @RickJames When you say "batching" into a single insert statement, do you mean building the SQL query as a string, or is there some way to still use prepared statements (to prevent SQL injection)? Would you still use a transaction? I don't know if the where statements can be combined or not, I'm confused on this. Each statement applies to a different row, which is identified through it's integer primary key.

Comment: @RickJames As an aside, I also looked into LOAD DATA INFILE, but it apparently only works for inserts and not updates and the updates I'm doing probably have 20x the amount of data as the inserts, so I don't know if it's worth implementing this method. I also struggled to find how to properly prevent sql injections with this method since it's not using prepared statements.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDO, so I can't help with building statements these statements.  It `addslashes()` is probably sufficient for building an SQL statement as a string.  If most of the time is spent in UPDATEs, then let's see some of them.  It may -- or may not -- be possible to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `PDO::beginTransaction()` follows the same rules as a `START TRANSACTION` statement in MySQL, more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html).

This means that MySQL will not lock the table immedialy, but will follow the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) rules.

Note that if you need to explicit lock some table(s) you can do:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->exec('LOCK TABLES t1, t2, ...');
```

Comment: So calling `PDO::beginTransaction()` in my script will not affect the execution of any queries in other scripts that are running concurrently? As I mentioned, a lot of time elapses between the beginning of my script (where `PDO::beginTransaction()` would be called) and the end (where `PDO::commit()` would be called) -- something like 50 seconds much of the time.

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::beginTransaction()` basically is `autocommit mode`. When you start a transaction ( `$mydb->beginTransaction();` ), it means that you **turn off** PDO AutoCommit.

And, that would never stop to go on the transaction until you stop by Commit or Roll it back.
e.g `$mydb->commit();`
When you stop that, it would turn into autocommit again.
Here, **you can control the transaction with commit or rollback**.

In related to the issue that you have huge queries to handle, I suggest you to do that step by step based on the priorities, as follows:

```
// start your transaction - means - stop auto commit.
If(query1 gets successful){
   If(query2 gets successful)
   {
      // Commit the transaction // stop the transaction
   }
   else
   {
      // Roll back the transaction 
   }
}
else{
   // Rollback the transaction
}
```

Be aware of using PDO transaction since the result cannot be undone. see this ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php